# PostgreSQL 10: How to add unique with constraint and default value -1

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-10

I'm looking to add unique values with constraint and with a default value of `-1` to `term` and `oldestyear`:

```
ALTER TABLE live_mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT live_mytable_uq
    UNIQUE (id,loan_type,coalesce(term,-1),coalesce(oldestyear, -1));
```

Because my goal is to be able to upsert -- insert if set doesn't exist and update the `apr` column if there's a conflict (if set exists but `apr` value is different):

```
INSERT INTO live_mytable(id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear) 
SELECT id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear
FROM   imp_mytable
  ON CONFLICT (id,loan_type,term,oldestyear) 
  DO UPDATE SET
     apr = excluded.apr;
```

The reason why I need a default value `-1` is because unique doesn't recognize null values, and columns `term` and `oldestyear` can be null.

I'm new to PostgreSQL so I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

My table design:
[image]

```
id       |loan_type      |apr   |term|oldestyear|
---------|---------------|------|----|----------|
    68459|auto new       |  3.50|  48|          |
    68459|auto new       |  3.50|  60|          |
    68459|auto new       |  3.99|  72|          |
    68459|auto used      |  3.24|  36|          |
    68459|auto used      |  3.74|  48|          |
    68459|auto used      |  3.74|  60|          |
    68459|auto used      |  3.99|  72|          |
    10066|auto new       |  2.99|  36|          |
    10066|auto new       |  3.29|  48|          |
```

My question is, how can I upsert from `imp_mytable` to `live_mytable` given that `term` and `oldestyear` can be null. And only update if `apr` is different when the unique set matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current data model you cannot, unless you do it [the old way](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-UPSERT-EXAMPLE) with a loop in PL/pgSQL that tries both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` until one of them succeeds.

Maybe you can use a value other than NULL to denote missing values in your columns, like -1. That would make it easy, and it might also simplify some of your queries.

Comment: I've added default value `-1::integer`  as seen in the picture, however, when I do the upsert function, it throws an error `ERROR: pq: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification` because there's no constraint. What constraint should I have along w/ my default value of `-1` would work w/ that upsert function?

Comment: Adding a `DEFAULT` value is not enough, you's actually have to update the table. Then you'd have to create the unique constraint as you wrote in your question (without the `coalesce` of course). Then it should work!

Comment: Although my column is set as default `-1` why is it when I import, the null field remains null and not `-1`? table schema: https://i.imgur.com/E95xsdm.png table values: https://i.imgur.com/ykpZkhd.png

Comment: Perhaps you explicitly insert NULL.

Comment: I thought adding default value `-1` means the value of `-1` would be added by default if column is null, I was mistaken, thanks!